# How do I get the displayname of the logged in user in EWS?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Exchange Autodiscovery will give me the user's Display Name via the `UserSettingName.UserDisplayName` property.

However, in cases where autodiscovery fails and connection needs to be done manually I can't figure out how to get the DisplayName.

I tried this, but I just get the users' email address:

```
 _service = new ExchangeService();
 _service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(exchangeSettings.EmailAddress, exchangeSettings.Password);
 _service.Url = new Uri(exchangeSettings.ExternalEwsUrl);

 NameResolutionCollection resolvedNames = _service.ResolveName(exchangeSettings.EmailAddress);
 exchangeSettings.UserDisplayName = resolvedNames.First().Mailbox.Name;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to use `ResolveName` and you want the displayName then you should use the overload to specify that the operation should return the AD contact information.  Then you can just use the `DisplayName` property.

```
NameResolutionCollection ncCol = 
 service.ResolveName("user@domain.com",ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,true);

Console.WriteLine(ncCol[0].Contact.DisplayName);
```