# Get current logged in user using Exchange SOAP web services

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices

we are using Exchange 2010 SP1 SOAP web services. I can't find the API to get the current (authenticated) user's information.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get the current user’s own email:

You could use ConvertId with a generic address and Exchange will then return the PrimarySMTP for that mailbox eg:

```
Folder Inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        AlternateId aiAlternateid = new AlternateId(IdFormat.EwsId, Inbox.Id.UniqueId, "mailbox@domain.com");
        AlternateIdBase aiResponse = service.ConvertId(aiAlternateid, IdFormat.EwsId);
        Console.WriteLine(((AlternateId)aiResponse).Mailbox);
```

AutoDiscover will also return the PrimarySMTP address of a Mailbox is you do a POX based discovery.

To check other addresses you can also use ResolveName:

[Resolve ambiguous names by using EWS in Exchange 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-resolve-ambiguous-names-by-using-ews-in-exchange-2013)

2. If you want to get the displayname of the logged in user in EWS:

If you are going to use ResolveName and you want the displayName then you should use the overload to specify that the operation should return the AD contact information. Then you can just use the DisplayName property.

```
    NameResolutionCollection ncCol = service.ResolveName("user@domain.com",ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,true);

    Console.WriteLine(ncCol[0].Contact.DisplayName);
```

For more information, you could refer these link:

[How do I get the displayname of the logged in user in EWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330515/how-do-i-get-the-displayname-of-the-logged-in-user-in-ews)

[How get the current user's own email address or check entered, using Exchange Web Services?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/52902d1f-5931-44df-b57b-e53dd1d8509d/ews-how-get-the-current-users-own-email-address-or-check-entered-using-exchange-web-services?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i don't have a ResolveName or any mailbox ID... I expect to send a request without any parms, since I'm already authenticated, so I just want to get back information about me (user name, email, etc.)

Comment: According to your reply, you could reference this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-user-settings-from-exchange-by-using-autodiscover

Comment: Alina, I looked at the link, and in all 3 options (EWS Managed API, SOAP Autodiscover, and POX Autodiscover)  you have to send an email address as a parm.  I don't want to send any parms - I want to get my own information based on my own authentication.  Do you have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any related Exchange SOAP solution, I'm not sure if  you could  try to use EWS library to get user information. For more information, you could reference this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-information-about-the-current-user